# Radio Buttons with own labels/components (Material UI)

Tags: material-ui, radio-button

I would like to have my own component for my specific radio button. But the component doesn't render correctly.

I have a RadioGroup like this:

```
const SampleComp = (props : MyProps) => {

    return <RadioGroup
        defaultValue="AllTime"
        name="Filter"
    >
        <FormControlLabel value="AllTime" control={<Radio />} label="All time" />
        <FormControlLabel value="TestLabel" control={<Radio />} label={<TestLabel/>} />
    </RadioGroup>
}
```

And I have a Testlabel to show a select component:

```
const TestLabel = () => {
    return  <FormControl fullWidth variant={'outlined'}>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Long text for label</InputLabel>
            <Select
                labelId="myField"
                id="myField"
                label="Long text for label"
                onChange={handleChange}
            >{[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map(s => <MenuItem key={s} value={s}>{'value ' + s}</MenuItem>)}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
}
```

In the end it looks like this:

[image]

I expected something like this:
[image]

Question: How can I render my component correctly when using in combination with a radio button? Or should this be done differently?

Answer (score 0):

I messed around trying to get something to work but it doesn't look possible + the [docs for FormControlLabel](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/form-control-label/#props) say it should take `A control element. For instance, it can be a Radio, a Switch or a Checkbox.`

It looks like you need to render a RadioGroup with an 'other' option and then either dynamically render or undisable a dropdown underneath the RadioGroup to achieve the behaviour you're after.

```
const SampleComp = () => {
  const [selectedRadioValue, setSelectedRadioValue] = useState('AllTime')
  const [selectedMenuItem, setSelectedMenuItem] = useState<string>()

  return (
    <>
      <RadioGroup
        value={selectedRadioValue}
        name="Filter"
        onChange={(_event, newValue) => setSelectedRadioValue(newValue)}
      >
        <FormControlLabel value="AllTime" control={<Radio />} label="All time" />
        <FormControlLabel value="Other" control={<Radio />} label="Other" />
      </RadioGroup>

      <TextField
        disabled={selectedRadioValue !== 'Other'}
        label="Long text for label"
        value={selectedMenuItem}
        onChange={(event) => setSelectedMenuItem(event.target.value)}
        fullWidth
        select
      >
        {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((s) => (
          <MenuItem key={s} value={s}>
            {'value ' + s}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
    </>
  )
}
```